# Simplest way to link/share data between android devices

Tags: android, synchronization, user-accounts

I'm just looking for a little guidance, or a point in the right direction here.

I'm creating a battery monitoring application.  I want to be able to link multiple android devices to the same users account, so that they can see the battery level of all their devices.

What is the simplest way to create a user profile, and share that data?

I was wanting to use "Sign in with Google" and possible a database storage solution, but I'm not sure if that is the easiest way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Google thing but from what little I've read about it it sounds like that would be a good way to go.  Parse.com is also a pretty easy service to use for data storage, and it supports access control lists to restrict data to a particular user.